# Kafka connect | Failed to deserialize data for topic | Error retrieving Avro key / value schema version for id | Subject not found error code: 40401

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

first of all thanks to @OneCricketeer for your support so far. I have tried so many configurations by now that I don't know what else I could try.

Using confluent `connect-standalone worker.properties sink.properties` to access an external stream.

Connection is working and i can see that a offset is loaded:

> INFO [my_mysql_sink|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-my_mysql_sink-0, groupId=connect-my_mysql_sink] Setting offset for partition gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts.clubs.spieleranalyse-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{
> **offset=2225**    , offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka8.pro.someurl.net:9093 (id: 8 rack: null)], epoch=0}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:844)

But afterwards i receive an error when newly messages come in:

> ERROR [my_mysql_sink|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=my_mysql_sink-0}    **Error converting message key in topic**    'gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts.clubs.spieleranalyse' partition 1 at offset 2225 and timestamp 1641459346507: **Failed to deserialize data for topic** gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts.clubs.spieleranalyse **to Avro:**
> **Caused by:** org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: **Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id** 422

> **Caused by:** io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: **Subject not found.; error code: 40401**

I do not get this.

**worker.properties:**

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

**sink.properties**

```
#key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net

#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net

#key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
#value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
#key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
#value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy

#pk.mode=record_key
#pk.fields=
```

As there is no pk set in mysql i wanted to record everything from stream.

As it says "**Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id 422**" I can see the following:

[screenshot_subject_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmBC7.png)

Do not wonder as it says JSON, this is just my ChromePlugin which interprets this as json.
Same is found for value. I also tried every combination in sink.properties which is commented out there.
I also be able to curl the latest schema for key and value (like):

> curl -s
> [https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKey/versions/latest|jq](https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKey/versions/latest%7Cjq)

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ClubWorkoutKey",
  "namespace": "com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "playerId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "tagId",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

It went a little further when I entered String Converter for key.converter and value.converter in sink.properties . But what must be wrong in my opinion, because Avro is passed here. With String there were then other problems, I would have had to set a pk and switch on delete etc.

Thanks for support.

*EDIT:

So, to me was given:

```
topic = gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts.clubs.spieleranalyse

schema.url = https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net
```

as well as: schema id url:

```
 https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKickValue/versions/latest/schema
```

and:

```
https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKickValue/versions/latest
```

For me its like a puzzle, i started with kafka 20 days ago. From there i tried the urls around and found the ones i posted for subject:

For Key: `https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKey/versions/latest/`

Schema: `{"subject":"gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKey","version":1,"id":422,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ClubWorkoutKey\",\"namespace\":\"com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"playerId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tagId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}]}"}`

For Values: `https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKickValue/versions/latest/`

and `https://schema-reg.pro.someurl.net/subjects/gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutPlayerMotionValue/versions/latest/`

Schemas: `{"subject":"gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutKickValue","version":1,"id":423,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ClubWorkoutKickValue\",\"namespace\":\"com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"playerId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}},{\"name\":\"tagId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ballSpeed\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ballSpeedFloat\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"float\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ballSpeedZone\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"enum\",\"name\":\"BallSpeedZone\",\"symbols\":[\"COLD\",\"MEDIUM\",\"HOT\",\"FIRE\",\"INVALID\"]}},{\"name\":\"confidence\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ingestionTime\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}],\"default\":null}]}"}`

and: `{"subject":"gamerboot.gamer.master.club-com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.WorkoutPlayerMotionValue","version":1,"id":424,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ClubWorkoutPlayerMotionValue\",\"namespace\":\"com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"playerId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}},{\"name\":\"absoluteDistance\",\"type\":\"float\"},{\"name\":\"averageSpeed\",\"type\":\"float\"},{\"name\":\"peakSpeed\",\"type\":\"float\"},{\"name\":\"tagId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"installationId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"averageSpeedZone\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"enum\",\"name\":\"AverageSpeedZone\",\"symbols\":[\"SPRINT\",\"HIGH_SPEED_RUN\",\"RUN\",\"JOG\",\"WALK\",\"STAND\",\"INVALID\"]}],\"default\":null,\"aliases\":[\"speedZone\"]},{\"name\":\"peakSpeedZone\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"enum\",\"name\":\"PeakSpeedZone\",\"symbols\":[\"SPRINT\",\"HIGH_SPEED_RUN\",\"RUN\",\"JOG\",\"WALK\",\"STAND\",\"INVALID\"]}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ingestionTime\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}],\"default\":null}]}"}`

MySQL table:

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type                                                                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| playerid         | varchar(100)                                                         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp        | mediumtext                                                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| absoluteDistance | float                                                                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| avarageSpeed     | float                                                                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| peakSpeed        | float                                                                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tagId            | varchar(50)                                                          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| installationId   | varchar(100)                                                         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| averageSpeedZone | enum('SPRINT','HIGH_SPEED_RUN','RUN','JOG','WALK','STAND','INVALID') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| peakSpeedZone    | enum('SPRINT','HIGH_SPEED_RUN','RUN','JOG','WALK','STAND','INVALID') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ballSpeed        | int(11)                                                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ballSpeedFloat   | float                                                                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ballSpeedZone    | enum('COLD','MEDIUM','HOT','FIRE','INVALID')                         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| confidence       | int(11)                                                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ingestionTime    | mediumtext                                                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Data expected in MySQL:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| playerid                             | timestamp     | absoluteDistance | avarageSpeed | peakSpeed | tagId          | installationId | averageSpeedZone | peakSpeedZone | ballSpeed | ballSpeedFloat | ballSpeedZone | confidence | ingestionTime |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| 59a70d45-5c00-4bb6-966d-b961b78ef5c1 | 1641495873505 |          5.76953 |       1.1543 |   1.22363 | 0104FLHBN009XD | null           | WALK             | WALK          |      NULL |           NULL | NULL          |       NULL | 1641496586458 |
| 59a70d45-5c00-4bb6-966d-b961b78ef5c1 | 1641484677624 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL | 0104FLHBN009XD | NULL           | NULL             | NULL          |        37 |        37.0897 | COLD          |         77 | 1641484896747 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

Data from avro-console looks like for the db entries:

```
{"playerId":"59a70d45-5c00-4bb6-966d-b961b78ef5c1","timestamp":1641484677624,"tagId":{"string":"0104FLHBN009XD"},"ballSpeed":{"int":37},"ballSpeedFloat":{"float":37.08966},"ballSpeedZone":"COLD","confidence":{"int":77},"ingestionTime":{"long":1641484896747}}

{"playerId":"59a70d45-5c00-4bb6-966d-b961b78ef5c1","timestamp":1641495873505,"absoluteDistance":5.7695312,"averageSpeed":1.1542969,"peakSpeed":1.2236328,"tagId":{"string":"0104FLHBN009XD"},"installationId":null,"averageSpeedZone":{"com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.AverageSpeedZone":"WALK"},"peakSpeedZone":{"com.ad.gamerboot.kafka.models.workouts.PeakSpeedZone":"WALK"},"ingestionTime":{"long":1641496586458}}
```

This is a fresh actual confluent installation. I updated just some hours ago Avro to: kafka-connect-avro-converter:7.0.1

Comment: Please provide your full schemas as text (value Avro, **and your database table** which will include the record fields). As well as examples of database rows you expect to actually get stored. Also, you need to set `TopicRecordNameStrategy`... If you show the logs sections of the Avro deserializer, it should record this value

Comment: Here's what you need to debug. In the error... `topic gamerboot.gamer.master.workouts.clubs.spieleranalyse`. In your post, the "topic" associated with schema 422 you've shown is only `gamerboot.gamer.master.club`, so have you shown the wrong url? If not, "Subject not found." makes sense (also, I swear I made a PR that logged exactly what subject was not found in that message; what versions of things are you using?)

Comment: Yeah... You'll want to upgrade at least the Avro converter and maybe Registry version https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/rest/exceptions/Errors.java#L26

Comment: Hey, i added hopefully all the informations u r asking for. Th@nks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, so you have at least three topics as part of the subject that don't match. I'm pretty sure neither of those subjects are going to work for `spieleranalyse` topic, only. You've also mentioned some `workouts` topic for `WorkoutKickValue` record, whose schema is never shown. You have a difference in `.club` and `.workouts` that dont match You could manually POST the expected schema to a subject with that name to "workaround" the error

Comment: Oh really? I couldn't map these somehow? Due to receiving the stream from console i thought it will be possible. So what would i need to do so? at least two topics for the values and two corresponding subjects?

Comment: I think the console consumer just uses the ID in the message and completely ignores the subject. It uses the `/schemas/ids/:val` API call... I'd need to double check that, but it's rather hidden in the source code. The converter does not.

Comment: wow, ok.  Just to get it right and due to that i'm just the receiver here. I have to ask the company which provides me that data for, at least two topics with the two value sets (kick and PlayerMotion) and there has to be the same subjectname in schemas? Key will not be necessary because there is no really primary key.

Comment: I think the reason you need to duplicate the information manually is because of type-erasure. For example, I see you have `WorkoutPlayerMotionValue` as a subject name, **however**, the actual record name in the schema body is a subclass(?) of `ClubWorkoutPlayerMotionValue`. Similar logic for `WorkoutKey`. But then you also have the second issue that includes `spieleranalyse` topic having no associated subjects (at least none you've shown)

Comment: Thank you very much, then I can try a lot with my little experience with kafka. I appreciate that you have invested your time here. I will write to the company and ask them to adjust the schemas so that they are usable for me. If this is not the case, may I come back to you, how a POST workaround could look like?

Comment: You just take the schema from one subject, e.g. the `/subjects/old/versions/latest/schema`, then issue that body as a POST request at `/subjects/new/versions`

Comment: Ah, you're talking about shifting schema from external url to my internal confluent schema. I think i get the idea behind, i will try this.

Comment: Well, needs to be the same registry instance, because it's the ID that matters, which is based on the MD5 hash of the schema text. This is just a way to map multiple subjects to the same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schemas was changed by company regarding RecordNameStrategy. Everything is working now.

Thanks